# Troubleshooting MSAL Authentication Issue: 'AADB2C90068 - The provided application is not valid against this service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, azure-authentication

**Question**:

I'm encountering an issue when attempting to test user authentication for my registered application using MSAL (Microsoft Authentication Library) via Visual Studio. The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

> Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you in.
> We track these errors automatically, but if the problem persists feel free to contact us. In the meantime, please try again.
> Correlation ID: 3078b652-992b-4970-be6e-5722dc67d353
> Timestamp: 2023-09-23 19:10:24Z
> AADB2C90068: The provided application is not valid against this service. Please use an application created via the B2C portal and try again.
> [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJ2w4.png)

**Problem Context**:

- I'm testing user authentication for an application registered in Azure AD B2C.
- I'm using MSAL, specifically the `microsoft.identity.client` package, within Visual Studio for this purpose.
- I've replaced my actual client ID with 'CLIENT_ID' in this question for security reasons.

My msal config code (Program.cs):

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MALAADB2C
{
    class Program
    {
        // ID of the App registered in AAD B2C
        private static string clientId = "CLIENT_ID"; //replaced actual id with CLIENT_ID

        // Authority
        private static string authority = "https://xxxx.b2clogin.com/tfp/xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_auth.xxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token"; // link modified for security purposes 

        // Permission scopes (empty)
        private static string[] scopes = new string[0];

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                .WithB2CAuthority(authority)
                .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost")
                .Build();

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Authenticating user...");
                AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(result.IdToken);
            }
            catch (MsalException exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

**Request for Assistance**:

I'm seeking guidance on potential causes and troubleshooting steps to resolve this 'AADB2C90068' error. Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this error and how to rectify it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance.

What I Expected: When users attempt to log in or sign up, I expected the authentication process to display a list of available identity providers, including those I've configured (e.g., Microsoft, Google, Facebook).

I might have messed up the configuration of my application on azure, I am not sure

Comment: When creating the app registration what was the 'supported account types' you selected?
For B2C User authentication flows it should be 'accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows)'

Answer (score 1):

> I agree with *@bolt-io*, the error usually occurs if you are not using application registered with **'Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows)'** option as Supported account type.

I registered one B2C **single tenant** application with supported account type as below:

[image]

When I ran the same code with above application's client ID, I too got **same error** as below:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, make sure to register the application with Supported account type as below:

[image]

When I ran the same code again by modifying the client ID, I got **login screen** with list of configured **identity providers** successfully like this:

[image]

After logging in with valid user account, I got **id token** in console like this:

[image]

To **confirm** that, I decoded the above id token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) and got **claims** successfully like this:

[image]