# Issue with "AADB2C90068: The provided application with ID '<Client ID>' is not valid against this service"

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I created an application programmatically using the Graph REST API and obtained the "Client ID" and "Client Secret." However, when attempting to use the "Get Code" API in the browser, I encountered an error.

The generated URL I used looks like this:

```
https://<TenantID>/<TenentName>.onmicrosoft.com/<SiginScope>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<YourClientID>&&response_type=code&scope=/https://<TenantName>.onmicrosoft.com/node-api/<YourAccessPolicyName>%20offline_access%20openid&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms
```

The error message received is:

> "Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you in. We track these errors automatically, but if the problem persists feel free to contact
> us. In the meantime, please try again. Correlation ID:  Timestamp:
>  AADB2C90068: The provided application with ID '' is
> not valid against this service. Please use an application created via
> the B2C portal and try again."
> Don't have an account? Contact us

I'm unsure why I'm receiving this error. How can I resolve this issue with the provided application ID not being recognized by the service?

Thank you for any guidance or insights on this matter.

Comment: Could you please include how you created application via Graph REST API? The error usually occurs if you created application with supported account type as single tenant or multi-tenant and using it to call B2C.

Comment: Sridevi, I have created the App using this Graph API "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/myorganization/applications"

Method: POST

Payload:

{
            displayName: <name>,
            signInAudience: '<value>',
            web: {
                redirectUris: <redirectURIs>,
            },
        };

Comment: What value you gave for `signInAudience` parameter?

Comment: "AzureADMyOrg" added for signInAudience

Comment: "AzureADMyOrg" is for single tenant applications that won't work for B2C calls which is causing the error. To resolve the error, you need to create application with `signInAudience` as **"AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"** that creates application with supported account type as _'Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows)'_

Comment: I have changed the signInAudience as "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount", but Still facing the same error,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255792/discussion-between-sridevi-and-shanthi-b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurred as you created application with "AzureADMyOrg" as `signInAudience` and using it to call B2C authorization requests.

> To **resolve** the error, you need to create B2C app registration properly with *"AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"* as `signInAudience` and update it by adding required permissions, followed by service principal creation.

In my case, I ran below `POST` request in **[Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)** signing in with B2C account to create app registration in it:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications
{
    "displayName": "MyApp30",
    "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
    "web": {
        "redirectUris": [
            "https://jwt.ms"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, update required application properties like adding **`openid`** and **`offline_access`** permissions with below PATCH request:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/appObjId/
{
    "requiredResourceAccess": [
        {
            "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "7427e0e9-2fba-42fe-b0c0-848c9e6a8182",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "37f7f235-527c-4136-accd-4a02d197296e",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Make sure to grant **admin consent** to added API permissions as below:

[image]

Note that, creating app registration via **Graph API** won't create service principal to it by default. So, you need to create **service principal** manually with separate request as below:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals
{
    "appId": "appClientId"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, I ran below **Authorize URL** in browser to get code by including `appClientId` where I got Sign in screen like this:

```
https://<b2ctenant>.b2clogin.com/<b2ctenant>.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_SUSI&client_id=<myappId>&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms&scope=openid&response_type=code&prompt=login
```

[image]

After authenticating with **valid** user account, I got **`code`** successfully in address bar as below:

[image]

**Reference:**
[AADB2C90068 - The provided application is not valid against this service - Stack Overflow by **me**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77164844/troubleshooting-msal-authentication-issue-aadb2c90068-the-provided-applicati?rq=2)

Comment: It's working actually, now i can able to see the sign in page and i can able sign in and then got the code. But when i hit the get refresh token API, getting the below error
API:https://<tenantName>.b2clogin.com/<tenantName>.onmicrosoft.com/<Policy>/oauth2/v2.0/token
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADB2C90080: The provided grant has expired. Please re-authenticate and try again. Current time: 1698721760, Grant issued time: 1698688232, Grant expiration time: 1698688532\r\nCorrelation ID: b786d95c-be31-4aad-bb97-4bbcd03a5c6e\r\nTimestamp: 2023-10-31 03:09:20Z\r\n"}

Comment: Note that, code will work for only one time. You will get that error if you use same code more than once. Try generating the code again and use it for token generation.

Comment: Sorry, i mistakenly posted the API, the above error as per your suggestion resolved. Below is the Refresh token API and error

API: https://<b2cTenantName>.b2clogin.com/<b2cTenantName>.onmicrosoft.com/<policyName>/oauth2/v2.0/token


error: {
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADB2C90205: This application does not have sufficient permissions against this web resource to perform the operation.\r\nCorrelation ID: 75d6eaa6-b3e5-4646-aad9-671771e17afb\r\nTimestamp: 2023-10-31 03:25:54Z\r\n"
}

Comment: Have you granted consent to added scope in application?

Comment: Yes, i did for openid and offline_access, but i don't know how to give the Read and Write scopes using API

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255796/discussion-between-sridevi-and-shanthi-b).